# Input (Scanner) variable in while loop

Tags: java

Im trying to make the program to ask for a percentage (grade) but I want it to ask again after the user has made the first input and has seen the output. I'm having trouble with the loop because the variable myMark is no assigned.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class passFail{


    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner result = new Scanner(System.in);
        int myMark = 0;

        while(myMark >=0 && myMark <=100){

            System.out.println("Please enter the percentage you have received:");
            myMark = result.nextInt();

            if(myMark <=49 && myMark >=0){

                System.out.println("You have failed!");
            }

            else if(myMark <=59 && myMark >=50){
                System.out.println("You have passed!");
            }

            else if(myMark <=69 && myMark >=60){
                System.out.println("You have received a Credit");
            }

            else if(myMark <=79 && myMark >=70){
                System.out.println("You have received a Distinction!");
            }

            else if(myMark <=100 && myMark >=80){
                System.out.println("You have received a High Distinction");
            }

            else{
                System.out.println("Please enter a whole number");
            }


        }

    }


}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop scanner from reading user input java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560468/stop-scanner-from-reading-user-input-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare your `myMark` before using it in `while` loop condition..
Also, you should declare your `Scanner` as instance variable..

```
public class Demo {
    private Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int myMarks = 0;
        while (myMarks >= 0 && myMark < 100) {
            // Rest is all same
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to define `myMark` first before using it. Something like below:

```
  Scanner result = new Scanner(System.in); 
  int myMark = result.nextInt();

  while(myMark >=0 && myMark <= 100){

        System.out.println("Please enter the percentage you have received:");
        myMark = result.nextInt();
      ..................
```

Comment: I'll also point out that you only need to create the Scanner once before the loop starts. You don't need to create it each time inside the loop.

Comment: This did not work. I have updated my question with the working code.

Comment: @Kronos: Instead of updating question, it would be clear for future users if you can post it as answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

**-** You have forgotten to `declare` the variable `myMark`.

**-** You have declare it to a `Type` (Data Type)

**Eg:**

```
int myMark;
```

**-** And it would be nicer if you place the `Scanner` **outside the loop**, cause you want to get the input only once...